# Dynamically change docker volume

Tags: docker

Basically I have one container that needs frequent rebuilds, and one that quite stable and changes very rarely. Second container needs folder from the first one.

It there any way to accomplish following task using volumes?

Creating container with volume:

```
# docker run -d -v /test-vol --name one ubuntu:14.04 cat
```

Creating second container with volume based on first container:

```
# docker run -d --volumes-from one --name two ubuntu:14.04 cat
```

Now I'm stopping first container, building it's new version.

**And here question goes**: I need some sort of magic to start it in such way that the second container start to see the new version of volume /test-vol.

From docker inspect perspective there is

```
"VolumesFrom": [
    "one"
]
```

so I thought may be I can create new container with the same name, but then I saw

```
"Volumes": {
    "/test-vol": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/[id]"
},
```

which explicitly links to old volume.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to dedicate a third container as a data volume container which could then be:

- mounted by the first for each rebuild
- mounted by the second as well

A data volume container can be mounted by several other containers.

Comment: Unfortunately data on volume isn't persistent and moreover that's main reason for container #1 rebuilds.

Comment: @Daniil data on volume is no more or less persistent than the data on volume you are currently defining on container one: one includes a data on volume, which makes one a data volume container.

Comment: @Daniil my point is: isolate the data part in a pure data volume container (that you won't have to stop and rebuild That would allow you to stop/rebuild one as many time as you want.

Comment: @Daniil Just to be clear: data on volume *is* persisted in `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir` (and referenced in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/id/conf.json`)